# Reverse polarity protection for battery powered application

Tags: mosfet, battery-operated, reverse-polarity

Im designing battery powered application and need reverse polarity protection.

My system specs: 4.5v(3x AA batteries) in and system running on 3.3v. Im using MCP1711T-33I/OT LDO to convert 4.5v to 3.3v. My system will take about 50 milliamps maximum. Therefore i can't obviously use any diodes since voltage drop and power waste will be too big. I read some threads and people tend to suggest P-channel MOSFET. I was looking for low rds(on) MOSFETS and all their packages seem so huge. Like this one:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2049687.pdf

Size isn't too big problem though(sot23 package would be perfect though). Can you suggest me anything else than P-channel MOSFET? If not, can you suggest me some decent P-channel MOSFET for my needs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seriously saying 3 mohm is huge? What type of wires do you use to connect these 3 AA batteries? Superconducting ones?

Comment: @Huisman He means package size

Comment: @DKNguyen I wonder... *they* refers to the *rds(on)* in the sentence. Moreover: *"Size isn't too big problem though"*

Comment: @Huisman I think he means he can deal with physical size, he just doesn't want to because it seems inappropriate for 50mA.

Comment: Yes, DKNguyen is right. Sorry for the confusion. I made up that sentence pretty badly. By saying huge i meant indeed package size and yes package size isn't too big problem, but it's huge for 50 mA in my opinion. It's power ratings are way over what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im using MCP1711T-33I/OT LDO to convert 4.5v to 3.3v.
>   ...
>   Therefore i can't obviously use any diodes since voltage drop and power waste will be too big.

If you are really concerned about voltage drop and power waste, I think you'd better focus on the MCP1711.
It is dissipating the difference between input voltage and output voltage so, 1.2 V * 50 mA = 60 mW at most.
Any R<sub>DS(ON)</sub> up to 1 Ω waists at most (50 mA)<sup>2</sup> * 1 Ω = 2.5 mW.

I'd suggest to replace the MCP1711 by a high efficient step-down converter (next to using the P-mosfets suggested by others for polarity protection).

Comment: Yes, i just realized that myself too. Just in case i will ask is DMP2100U-7 MOSFET decent? I have burned down some MOSFETS in the past since i couldn't choose the correct one(http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1669947.pdf).

Comment: Also just to be sure, will MCP1603/B/L be better choice? http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1669947.pdf

Comment: @MiniTamm Yes, DMP2100U-7 is a good choice if it is for personal use (for product development it's not recommended for new design, use DMP2045U)

Comment: And the MCP1603/B/L looks a nice candidate too (I briefly looked at it)

Answer (score 0):

With RDS of say 1 ohm you would have 50mV drop. This drop reduces the amount of energy you can drain from the battery a little, before the voltage drops too low, but otherwise it doesn't effect your system. Power loss in the RDS doesn't matter because you use a linear regulator so total power loss doesn't change.  So I'd say you can easily find good enough MOSFET even in SOT23 package.

Comment: Im sorry, but what you mean by: _Power loss in the RDS doesn't matter because you use a linear regulator so total power loss doesn't change._?

Comment: A linear regulator works so that it adjusts its resitance so that it "burns" the excess voltage to achieve the correct output voltage. If you have some series resitance with a linear regulator it does part of the "burning". As a result the total power dissipated in the regulator and the series resistance is the same that the linear regulator would dissipate alone.

Answer (score 0):

Even ~500mOhm RDSon is plenty low for this.You are searching for too low an RDSon for your application. I use the IRLML6402 (65mOhm) or IRLML6302 (600mOhm) because that's what I like. It makes little difference at 50mA. You'll notice a 30mV drop as much as you will notice a 3mV drop.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Si2305 which works great. Check it out. It dropped <0.2v  @150mA